# Scroll tabbar programmatically + Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabcontainer

I want TabBar to scroll when user tap on previous/ next arrow. Not to change tab, just scroll. I check TabController properties, but didn't found anything for this. Is there any material widget available for same? Please share how can I achieve this feature?

UI [image: ref]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using `scrollController`.
Use a ScrollController to control the horizontal scrolling of the TabBar. The scrollTabBar function is used to scroll the TabBar when the previous and next arrow buttons are pressed. This approach allows you to scroll the TabBar without changing the current tab index.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TabBarDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabBarDemoState createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void scrollTabBar(int scrollAmount) {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      final maxScrollExtent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      final newPosition = _scrollController.offset + scrollAmount;
      if (newPosition >= 0 && newPosition <= maxScrollExtent) {
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          newPosition,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Scrollable TabBar Example'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              scrollTabBar(-50); // Scroll to the left
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onPressed: () {
              scrollTabBar(50); // Scroll to the right
            },
          ),
        ],
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 4'),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
          labelColor: Colors.blue,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController, // Control the scroll
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 4, // Adjust width as needed
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Center(child: Text('Tab 1 Content')),
                  Center(child: Text('Tab 2 Content')),
                  Center(child: Text('Tab 3 Content')),
                  Center(child: Text('Tab 4 Content')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simply not possible. but there is a alternative solution

use this package for the tab bar
https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

and use pageview for tabbar view.

assign the controller for pageview. and another controller for the scrolable list.

if clicking the arrow button change the scroll position of the second scrolable list

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but I prefer to achieve this using material widgets only.